# Display custom html in jQuery plugin Galleria's photo caption

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, galleria

Galleria is a very nice gallery plugin, but the information displayed in the photo caption (if you click the *i* symbol) is generated by the plugin.

[image]

I am trying to find a solid way (content separation from presentation, cross-browser, standard-compliant, if possible) to be able to insert my custom html code (i.e. links and styles) in this caption text.

The plugin supports html caption with the [dataConfig](http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/options/dataConfig/#default-extractions-from-the-html-element) option, but it strips `<a href=""></a>` off.

To overcome this stripping, I found this to work:

**JS**

```
var _tit = $(img).next('h3').html();
var _info = $(img).siblings('.info').html();
var _url = $(img).siblings('.info a').attr("href");
var _user = $(img).siblings('.info a').children().html();
var _desc = _info + "<a href="+_url+">"+ _user +"</a>";
return { title: _tit, description: _desc };
```

**HTML**

```
<span class="info">Subida por <a href="http://www.manolito.com">Manolito</a></span>
```

When ideally, a simple `description: $('.info').html()` should suffice...

Comment: here http://getsatisfaction.com/galleria/topics/add_a_link_inside_the_description are some not-so-good solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers of Galleria have now [fixed this with the new version](http://galleriajs.tumblr.com/post/8091630096/introducing-in-1-2-5-html-layer).

Answer (score 1):

Its supported by galleria, have a look here: http://galleria.aino.se/docs/1.2/options/dataConfig/

Comment: I have tried this, but didn't work in my specific case... editing cuestion.

Comment: updated with the code... question has boiled down to "how to prevent `<a>` stripping beatifully?"